# Meaning of ことにはわからない

Tags: grammar

> それだって、実際に選んでみない**ことにはわからない**のだ。

I often see something like 私にわからない meaning "I don't understand", but what does it mean when the particle に attaches to こと?

From the context I think what this sentences means is "Nevertheless, I must try to make a choice". So I'm thinking **ことにはわからない** means something like "it is not possible" but I don't see that supported in any of the dictionaries where I checked the definitions of わかる.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(A) + ないことには + (B) + ない` is a fixed construction meaning "not (B) if not (A)" or "not (B) without/unless (A)".

> 実際に選んでみないことにはわからないのだ。
>   I don't understand it unless I actually choose it.

[JGram has many examples of this pattern.](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=naikotoniha) (Note: This page contains some examples not related to this pattern. Ignore examples #259 and #5258 for now.)

This ～ないことには is interchangeable with ～ないと/～なければ, but it sounds slightly stiffer, I think. And ～ないことには is almost always followed by another negative expression.

> - 宿題をしないと怒られる。: OK
> - 宿題をしなければ怒られる。: OK
> - 宿題をしないことには怒られる。: awkward
> - 宿題をしないことには眠れない。: OK